# Use React Dev Tool in developing MetaMask

Tags: metamask, react

I am new to MetaMask, and learning how MetaMask works. I found MetaMask UI was implemented with React, so I tried to use React Dev Tool, but I am not able get it working. Please help.

1. I started stand alone react dev tool (https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/packages/react-devtools/README.md)
2. I added a line `<script src="http://localhost:8097"></script>` in `app/home.html`
3. I used `npm start` to have it built in `dist` directory
4. I used Chrome Extension (developer mode) to load that directory.
5. I am seeing in Chrome console: Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:8097/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

I tried to manipulate app/Manifest.json, but failed to make it work.
I tried dozens of time on different combinations of "content_security_policy", and some time the React Dev Tool worked, but the MetaMask stuck at initial loading screen.